# sap VizFrame fireSelectData is not fireing

Tags: svg, sapui5

I have a bar chart written with vizframe and i want to call the `fireSelectData` function with the following parameter:

```
var oSelection = {
  data: [{
     target: $('.v-datapoint')[29],
     data: [{
        ctx: {
           path: {
              mg: 0,
              mi: 0,
              dii_a1: 0,
              dii_a2: 0 
           },
           val: 82.2      
        } 
     }]
   }],
   name: "selectData"
}
var frame = this.getView().byId('vizFrameId')
frame.fireSelectData(oSelection)
```

where `$('.v-datapoint')[29]` is the `<g>` svg tag and `28.2` is the value of a column. I'm not sure if these are the correct parameters for the object.

Which is really not clear for me is the `path`. Which value should be there for `mg, mi, dii_a1` and `dii_a2`?

Comment: Do you want to perfrom data point selection initially? Or do you want to do something after user had clicked on certain data point on chart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to select specific values you can use the vizframe's `vizSelection` function.

```
oVizFrame.vizSelection([{data : dataPoint}], {clearSelection : true});
```

the first parameter is an array of datapoints wich are in the model of the vizframe. You can get those objects with `oVizFrame.getModel().getProperty('/yourProperty')`

if you set `clearSelection: true` the previous selection will be cleared.